# Http request is executing two times in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am making an api call to my server. This is the component code

```
formData(username:string, password:string) {
    if (username == "" || password == "") {
        this.message = "Fields are empty";
      } else {
      this.loginservice.login(username,password).subscribe(heroes => this.serverRes = heroes);
    }
}
```

This is the service code

```
login(username:string,password:string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('loginService','called');
    return of(this.http.post<any>(this.configUrl,
        {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
        }));      
}
```

I don't know why it's making api calls twice. First api request without request body and second api request is with request body.

Comment: It checks whether a server can respond or it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters. For details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: thanks..it's working fine..but another issue. I am calling form data function on button click. When I click the button, api call is going but login function in service returning empty response. If I click it again then only response is coming..can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change Observable to Promise can resolve your problem and error described in the comment:

> thanks..it's working fine..but another issue. I am calling form data function on button click. When I click the button, api call is going but login function in service returning empty response. If I click it again then only response is coming..can you help me with this

```
login(username:string, password:string): Promise<any> {
  console.log('loginService','called');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post<any>(this.configUrl,
      {
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      })
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        resolve(res);
      },(error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        reject(error);
    }
  }    
}


formData(username:string, password:string) {
  if (username == "" || password == "") {
    this.message = "Fields are empty";
  } else {
    this.loginservice.login(username,password)
      .then((heroes: any) => {
        this.serverRes = heroes
      }
      .catch(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         //do something with error
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you return `of` of your post function?? don't do that, instead, just return the post.

```
login(username:string,password:string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('loginService','called');
    return this.http.post<any>(this.configUrl,
        {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
        });      
}
```